# bypassing metacharacter filtering

Tags: sql-injection

So I am trying to bypass metacharacter filtering.

I want to know how do you start an injection. For example if the `'` is filtered how do you begin the input.

If i did `' or 1=1#` without filtering it would work. But since the `'` is filtered how do you begin an injection. I tried `hexidecimal 27 or 1=1#`.

Comment: Sometimes it's possible to inject without escaping the SQL query if string concatenation is used.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on which characters are being filtered, the specifics of the filter, as well as the specifics of the SQL injection vulnerability.

Filters can be bypassed with encodings that are interpreted differently by the filter versus the browser, the injection may be possible without the character (if the string is not quoted), a different character can be used sometimes, or [two injections can be used in conjunction to escape quotes in a useful way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030937/bypassing-sql-character-blacklist-filtering/58120668#58120668).

**OWASP** has an [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) (originally started by RSnake) which collects a lot of these techniques.